# MapBox Symbol doesn't act like markers properly (clustering, click..)

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

I am trying to make moving cars on MapBox using new promising GL Symbol layer/source. It looks very nice both on android and ios, but I faced with two impossibilities.

1. Symbols are always clustering. setIconAllowOverlap() and  setIconIgnorePlacement() don't help: on some zoom it WILL be clustered. On both platforms.

**How can I disable symbols clustering completely**?

---

UPDATE: the code and even fast solution! (possibly bug? see comment at withTextField)

```
in onStyleLoaded():
...
carManager = new SymbolManager(mapView, mapboxMap, style);
carManager.setIconAllowOverlap(true);//doesn't help
carManager.setIconIgnorePlacement(true);//doesn't help
...

in drawCarFunction():
...
            SymbolOptions carOptions = new SymbolOptions()
                    .withLatLng(latLng)
                    .withIconImage(carPlate)
                    //.withTextField(carPlate) //!!!! here it will cluster if text exists, and will NOT - without any text
                    ;
            Symbol car= carManager.create(carOptions);
            carSymbols.add(car);
...
```

---

Next question:

2. On Android we have symbolManager.addClickListener() , but how could I **catch a click on iOS**? I know I can catch the tap, calculate nearest marker etc but

**How to get symbol click simpler in swift?**

3. In *Moving cars task* I should enumerate existing cars, move running, add newest. Where should I store cars IDs to get it later on next move? Where are no even symbol.setTag() option... Storing IDs in snippet (as on GMaps) is not that choice I expected from MapBox. Sure, I can make an array of pairs "car ID = symbol ID", but

**How to store my own UID in the symbol?**

UPDATE: the code. Note the comment near getTag()

```
void moveExistingCarOrAddNew(int carId, LatLng newLocation){ 
  for (int i = 0; i < carManager.getAnnotations().size(); i++) { 
    if (carManager.getAnnotations().get(i).getTag()==carId){ //but no getTag() here, I should fit data into text fields
       car.setLatLng(newLocation); //move! 
    } else { 
       ...//create new marker as shown above } 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you narrow your problem down a specific thing and show the code that is giving you the problem?

Comment: I've updated my questions. Also I've found the solution of first one, but this is probably the bug.

Comment: Actually, my questions is for MapBox support team mostly, because first piece of code is from official example

Comment: I think you can set symbol's layout style `icon-allow-overlap` and `text-allow-overlap` as `true` for unclustering.

Comment: I set it already, don't work. They are clustering on both platforms

Comment: I'd recommend splitting your questions into single issues by platform (iOS or Android) Answering all 4 questions in one response for different platforms would be a bit muddled.

Comment: Hey you got the solution or not? I am facing same problem in android .Please help me out.

Comment: Nope. I had to use a lot of individual SymbolLayers for every car.